# Regex to match double quoted strings without variables inside php tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Basically I need a regex expression to match all double quoted strings inside PHP tags without a variable inside.

Here's what I have so far:

```
"([^\$\n\r]*?)"(?![\w ]*')
```

and replace with:

```
'$1'
```

However, this would match things outside PHP tags as well, e.g HTML attributes.

Example case:

```
<a href="somelink" attribute="value">Here's my "dog's website"</a>
<?php
    $somevar = "someval";
    $somevar2 = "someval's got a quote inside";
?>
<?php
    $somevar3 = "someval with a $var inside";
    $somevar4 = "someval " . $var . 'with concatenated' . $variables . "inside";
    $somevar5 = "this php tag doesn't close, as it's the end of the file...";
```

it should match and replace all places where the `"` should be replaced with a `'`, this means that html attributes should ideally be left alone.

Example output after replace:

```
<a href="somelink" attribute="value">Here's my "dog's website"</a>
<?php
    $somevar = 'someval';
    $somevar2 = 'someval\'s got a quote inside';
?>
<?php
    $somevar3 = "someval with a $var inside";
    $somevar4 = 'someval ' . $var . 'with concatenated' . $variables . 'inside';
    $somevar5 = 'this php tag doesn\'t close, as it\'s the end of the file...';
```

It would also be great to be able to match inside script tags too...but that might be pushing it for one regex replace.

I need a regex approach, not a PHP approach. Let's say I'm using regex-replace in a text editor or JavaScript to clean up the PHP source code.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback()` to match the php tags, and in the callback use your regular expression.

Comment: @HamZa What if there is something like this in the php: `$a = '<?php echo 'booooo!; ?>';` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Can you tell me the chance of that happening in general context ?

Comment: @HamZa The chance is relatively high. At least if someone has detected this and want's to exploit it. Parsing and manipulating source code requires a stateful parser. Using the tokenizer extension might be a starting point.

Comment: Well there is 2 options: taking the risk or using a full parser the hard way.

Comment: @HamZa check my answer. `tokenizer` does a good job. I think the function is an reasonable effort for the problem as any problem with a simple regex solution would lead to a corrupted source file.

Comment: Thanks both but I should have been more clear in my question, I need a regex based approach not a php based approach (not language specific)

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair You must be really precise. If you want a regex solution, you must provide what regex flavor you will be using. Since regexes may differ from language/environment to another. For example, Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds `(?<!)`. IMO it's (almost) impossible to replace what you want in a single regex without callback.

Comment: Hmm ok that's a bummer, I guess I'll have to rely on something else then. I literally wanted something I could use for a regex-replace in a text editor or maybe a javscript regex replace so I could create a handy jsfiddle for cleaning up some php.

Comment: Regexes are probably *not* the solution for the kind of problem you're trying to tackle. There is too much complexity they just aren't designed to handle. You really need to use a construct that understands the language.

Comment: @vks Yes it is, basically using single quoted string literals where acceptable, double quoted otherwise.

Comment: @Jon Surrell indeed I'm thinking it may not be possible now with a simple regex replace, rather it will require some sort of parser.

Comment: I think that's your best course of action. Regexes are known to be bad at this.

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair Using JavaScript's regex flavor is a terrible joke since it's one of the poorest regex engine there is. Also text editors have different regex engines, which one are you planning to use?

Comment: @DJDavid98 stating that the answer is "incorrect" is in itself incorrect. It does the job in a correct and safe way. Also see the edit history, no wonder this thread is a bit messed up.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

This is really too complex complex to be done with regex. Especially not a simple regex. You might have better luck with nested regex, but you really need to lex/parse to find your strings, and *then* you could operate on them with a regex.

## Explanation

You can *probably* manage to do this.
You can *probably* even manage to do this well, maybe even *perfectly*.
But it's not going to be easy.
It's going to be very *very* difficult.

Consider this:

```php
Welcome to my php file. We're not "in" yet.

<?php
  /* Ok. now we're "in" php. */

  echo "this is \"stringa\"";
  $string = 'this is \"stringb\"';
  echo "$string";
  echo "\$string";

  echo "this is still ?> php.";

  /* This is also still ?> php. */

?> We're back <?="out"?> of php. <?php

  // Here we are again, "in" php.

  echo <<<STRING
    How do "you" want to \""deal"\" with this STRING;
STRING;

  echo <<<'STRING'
    Apparently this is \\"Nowdoc\\". I've never used it.
STRING;

  echo "And what about \\" . "this? Was that a tricky '\"' to catch?";

  // etc...
```

Forget matching variable names in double quoted strings.
Can you just match all of the string in this example?
It looks like a nightmare to me.
SO's syntax highlighting certainly won't know what to do with it.

Did you consider that variables may appear in [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) strings as well?

I don't want to think about the regex to check if:

1. Inside `<?php` or `<?=` code
2. Not in a comment
3. Inside a quoted quote
4. What type of quoted quote?
5. Is it a quote of that type?
6. Is it preceded by `\` (escaped)?
7. Is the `\` escaped??
8. etc...

## Summary

You can probably write a regex for this.
You can probably manage with some backreferences and lots of time and care.
It's going to be hard and your probably going to waste a lot of time, and if you ever need to *fix it*, you aren't going to understand the regex you wrote.

## See also

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1432801). It's worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function that utilizes the tokenizer extension to apply `preg_replace` to PHP strings only:

```
function preg_replace_php_string($pattern, $replacement, $source) {
    $replaced = '';
    foreach (token_get_all($source) as $token) {
        if (is_string($token)){
            $replaced .= $token;
            continue;
        }
        list($id, $text) = $token;
        if ($id === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) {
            $replaced .= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
        } else {
            $replaced .= $text;
        }
    }
    return $replaced;
}
```

In order to achieve what you want, you can call it like this:

```
<?php
    $filepath = "script.php";
    $file = file_get_contents($filepath);
    $replaced = preg_replace_php_string('/^"([^$\{\n<>\']+?)"$/', '\'$1\'', $file);
    echo $replaced;
```

The regular expression that's passed as the first argument is the key here. It tells the function to only transform strings to their single-quoted equivalents if they do not contain `$` *(embedded variable `"$a"`)*, `{` *(embedded variable type 2 `"{$a[0]}"`)*, a new line, `<` or `>` (HTML tag end/open symbols). It also checks if the string contains a single-quote, and prevents the replacement to avoid situations where it would need to be escaped.

While this is a PHP solution, it's the most accurate one. The closest you can get with any other language would require you to build your own PHP parser in that language to some degree in order for your solution to be accurate.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but I'm afraid I can't use PHP for what I need it for!

Comment: What language are you about to use?